# Include errors while working in the kernel

Tags: c, linux, hash, include, implementation

I am making a implementation of Hash_Drbg.

The original source code can be found here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/crypto/drbg.c

I have taken out the parts of the code I need for my implementation and think it should work when I compile it.

When I compile I get errors regarding the includes.

For example:

```
fatal error: crypto/drbg.h: No such file or directory.
```

This can be easily fixed by downloading the kernel and modifiying the include found at the top of the source code. When I do that, I am meet with the same error for the includes inside the `drbg.h` header.

For example:

```
fatal error: linux/scatterlist.h: No such file or directory.
```

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: Do you use compiler flags `-I` to specify the correct include directories?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the Linux kernel headers which allow you to compile code against the Linux kernel.

You should install linux headers. Which flavour you are using? Please change below commands accordingly.

To install just the headers in Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

To install the entire Linux kernel source in Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-source
```

Note that you should use the kernel headers that match the kernel you are running.

And then you can add that to your Makefile as:

```
KDIR =//usr/src/linux-headers

all:
 $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```